# Splitting strings and re-ordering in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, split

I'm trying to rearrange a string that contains a full name so that the second name is displayed before the first name.

I've managed to split the string using the code below, however when I build it seems to be returning in array format ["second name", "first name"] rather than a string "second name, "first name".

Any help appreciated!

```
def name_shuffler(str)
   name_parts = str.split(" ")
   first_name, last_name = name_parts[1], name_parts[0]
end
```

Comment: name_parts.join(" ")` at the end of your method should work.

Comment: Done - this solves the latter problem, but the names are no longer in reverse order?

Comment: That's because `name_parts` is still in the same order; you only split it on `" "`, so if you join it on `" "` again, you'll get the original string (with any consecutive spaces collapsed into one).

Comment: Ah, well maybe `name_parts.reverse.join(' ')` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just join the two parts:

```
def name_shuffler(str)
    name_parts = str.split(" ")
    [name_parts[1], name_parts[0]].join(" ")
end

name_shuffler "one two" # => "two one"
```

Although you're going to want to think about handling input with no spaces, or more name parts than two.

Answer (score 1):

```
def name_shuffler(str)
  str.split(" ").reverse.join(" ")
end

name_shuffler("John Doe") #=> "Doe John"
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A regex way.

```
"John Smith".gsub(/(\w+) (\w+)/,'\2 \1') #=> "Smith John"
```

A rotating way.

```
"John Smith".split(' ').rotate.join(' ') #=> "Smith John"
```